# Computing a nasty integral (probably with computer algebra system)

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, special-functions, closed-form, computer-algebra-systems

I'm trying to do this integral, not sure if it is possible:

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\left(\, -\,{x^{2} \over y^{2}}\,\right)
\exp\left(\,-\,{y^{2} \over z^{2}}\,\right)
\exp\left(\, -\left[\,z-1-\log\left(\, z\,\right)\,\right]\,\right)
\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z
$$

I am happy with computer algebra solutions if they exist. So far I have had some issues with Maple, which just returns back the original integral.

Comment: In which context does this integral arise?

Comment: If I assume $x\neq 0$ (and $x$ real), then Mathematica solves the $y$ integral, and leaves $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}z^2}{2}\exp(1-z-2|x|/z)\,dz$ uncalculated. Not sure if it helps you, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** Your integral may be reduced to a generalized incomplete gamma function that has been previously studied.

- **Step 1.** Integrating with respect to $y$ gives

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{z^2}-\frac{x^2}{y^2}\right)dy&=\exp{\left(-\frac{2 x}{ z}\right)}\int_0^\infty \exp{-\left(\frac{y}{z}-\frac{x}{y}\right)^2}dy\\\\
&=z\:\exp{\left(-\frac{2 x}{ z}\right)}\int_0^\infty \exp{(-Y^2)}dY\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}z\:\exp{\left(-\frac{2 x}{ z}\right)}\\\\
\end{align}
$$

- **Step 2.** Integrating with respect to $z$ gives, for $x\geq 0$:

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}z\:\exp{\left(-\frac{2 x}{ z}\right)}\cdot\exp(-(z-1-\log(z)))dz\\\\&=\frac{e\:\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_1^\infty z^2\:\exp{\left(-z-\frac{2 x}{ z}\right)} dz\\\\
&=\frac{e\:\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \Gamma (3,1;2x)
\end{align}
$$ where $\Gamma (\nu,x;b)$ is *a generalized incomplete gamma function* whose some properties have been considered [here (M.A. Chaudhry, N.M. Temme and E.J.M. Veling)](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0377042795000186/1-s2.0-0377042795000186-main.pdf?_tid=f71c069e-95e9-11e4-98d3-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1420579463_d6a71dfca5f0fc3e90dfa802a92abea1) (click on the free pdf) or [here (Frank E. Harris)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042707002014#bib7). See also various references at the end of these papers.

I'm interested in knowing the context of this integral.

Comment: Thanks! It occurs when calculating a tail-bound of a product of three functions with known tail-bounds.

Comment: I only don't understand the second line in step 2, when you do the substitution. Since $Y$ is no longer changing linearly, how do you justify it?

Comment: @EricGregor Do you mean in step 1? thanks.

Comment: Yes, forgive me. Step 1b, when you integrate with respect to Y now. This substitution is not clear to me.

Comment: @EricGregor After a change of variable $u=y/z$, I've used this general fact:$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(u-\frac{s}{u}\right)\mathrm{d}u=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(u)\: \mathrm{d}u, \quad s>0. \quad (*)
$$ Proved, for example, at the end of this post:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896156/integrating-ea-x2-x2-1-eb-x2/896387#896387

Answer (score 2):

As user **mickep** already pointed out in the comment section, the integral can be rewritten as

$\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2~e~I''(1)$, where $I(a)=\displaystyle\int_1^{+\infty}\exp\bigg(\!\!-az-\frac{2x}z~\bigg)~dz$. Now, if the lower integration limit

would have been $0$ instead of $1$, then we'd have $J(a)=2~\sqrt{\dfrac{2x}a}~K_1\Big(2\sqrt{2ax}\Big)$, which, after

being twice differentiated with regard to *a*, yields $J''(1)=4x\sqrt{2x}~K_3\Big(2\sqrt{2x}\Big)$. As it stands,

however, we'd need incomplete [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) to express $I(a)$, as already hinted at by Prof.

**Olivier Oloa** in his answer. Unfortunately, there is no universally accepted notational con-

vention regarding such functions.